# Search box and hitting enter key to execute a function

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a searchbox where the user of my app can type in a word. I would like to be able to click the "Enter" key on the phones keyboard to start the search, but that doesn't work so instead I need to have a button to launch the search function.

```
<TextBox Name="txtSearchBox" InputScope="Search"/>
```

How can I make the enter key launch a function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the key pressed in the Key_Up event and compare it to the `enter` key

```
private void txtSearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) 
             DoSearchHere();
    }
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! I also had to set the set the focus to another element on the page to get rid of the keyboard. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer doesn't work anymore in C#

so here is my code that does work

```
    private void searchbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            searchButton_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```